# How do I set the font size in a prawn table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

How do I set the font size in a PDF table using the prawn gem?

When I call prawn like the following:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => 'LEGAL', :page_layout => :landscape)
pdf.table data, 
    :header => true,
    :column_widths => widths,
    :font_size => 7,
    :row_colors => ["EEEEEE", "FFFFFF"]
```

I get an NoMethodError

```
undefined method `font_size=' for #<Prawn::Table:0x6ce37ea4>
```

When I remove the ":font_size => 7", it renders but I get an undesirable font size.

I am using prawn 0.12.0, ruby 1.9.3p194, and Rails 3.1.9.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to apply the size property to the cell text directly. Here is how to do this:

```
pdf.table data, 
  :header => true,
  :column_widths => widths,
  :cell_style => { size: 7 },
  :row_colors => ["EEEEEE", "FFFFFF"]
```

Source: http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf

Answer (score 4):

*:font_size => 7* not works.

**The correct way is** :size => 7

```
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => 'LEGAL', :page_layout => :landscape)
    pdf.table data, 
    :header => true,
    :column_widths => widths,
    :size => 7,
    :row_colors => ["EEEEEE", "FFFFFF"]
```

Comment: What is your prawn version?

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf.table(data) do
  style row(0), :font_size => 7
end
```

I believe for 0.12.0 you could also use something like this:

```
table([[ {:font_size => 7 } ]])
```

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG

Comment: First example (block) raises NoMethodError "undefined method `font_size=' for #<Prawn::Table::Cell::Text:0x6b479454>"

Comment: Try size= instead of font_size=. "style row(0), :font_size => 7" does not work, but "style row(0), :size => 7" does work in more recent versions of Prawn.